# Localizing HTML files in XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, localization, uiwebview

I have a localized iOS application in which I wish to include some localized HTML files. I can't work out how to do it.

Currently, my folder structure looks like this:

```
/myapp
   /en.lrproj
       /Localizable.strings
   /fr.lrproj
       /Localizable.strings
   /webviews
      /view1
         /index.html
         /pic1.png
      /view2
         /index.html
         /pic2.png
```

As you can see, I currently have the views organized into their own folders with the associated images.

In XCode, when I selected the Localizable.strings files I can add new localizations. When searching for the solution to this problem I see that other people have done the same for the HTML files, however when I select the HTML files there are no options displayed for localizations, so I'm wondering if the folder structure is the problem.

On the other hand, I don't know how to structure the HTML into language code folders whilst not replicating the graphics that have to be along side.

Clearly I'm not understanding something - what do I need to do to get this working?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrange your index.html right next to the Localized.strings, keep the pics in the web views directory:

```
/myapp
   /en.lrproj
       /Localizable.strings
       /view1/index.html
       /view2/index.html
   /fr.lrproj
       /Localizable.strings
       /view1/index.html
       /view2/index.html
   /webviews
      /view1
         /pic1.png
      /view2
         /index.html
         /pic2.png
```

The build a file path:

```
NSArray* availableLocalizations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations];    
NSArray* userPrefered = [NSBundle preferredLocalizationsFromArray:availableLocalizations forPreferences:[NSLocale preferredLanguages]];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"view" forLocalization:[userPrefered objectAtIndex:0]];
```

The picture in the html tree are now similar to

```
/myapp/en.lrproj/view1/index.html  
/myapp/webviews/view1/pic1.png
```

Inside your index.html make the `<img>` tags point to `../../../webview/pic1.png` 
(Not sure about the number of `../`'s that you need. You might want to open a terminal, navigate to /myapp/en.lrproj/view1/ and test with `ls ../../../webview/pic1.png`. )

Comment: Hi. I'm having problems setting this up. From Xcode, how can I add the directory structure to the languages resource directories? If I add an  XCode "group" then I lose the structure when it's deployed.  If I add a folder reference then I can't add new localizations via Xcode, and the files aren't picked up by my translator tool (Linguan).

Comment: Use Finder to place the files, then back inside Xcode add the files to the project. If the files already are part of the project use the utilities view to update the path. Sorry, can't help you with Linguan.

Comment: Right. I had to add the xx.lproj files directly to the project as folder references so that they'd be copied with their internal folder structure intact. Xcode coped with that fine. I could then do as you suggested (with a bug fix, since you can't pass an array to the forLocalization: parameter).

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. I have changed it to read `forLocalization:[userPrefered objectAtIndex:0]];`

Answer (score 2):

I assume "webviews/view1/index.html" is English, and "webviews/view2/index.html" is French.

```
NSString *dir = NSLocalizedString("webviews/view1", @"webdir");
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:dir];
```

in Localizable.strings of French

```
/* webdir */
"webviews/view1" = "webviews/view2";
```

I tested above code using below in a ViewController.

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
```

"webviews" directory should be a "folder reference" in Xcode, not a group.
(Blue directory icon, not yellow one)

Also, be careful not to add a slash after the directory name, like "webviews/view2/".
I found that this could be a problem when I run that on iOS 5.x(I tested it on 5.0.1 and 5.1.1). But no problem on iOS 6.1.2.