# How to load localized html file from WKWebView?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, wkwebview

1st StackOverflow question for me...

!! Objective-C !!

I'm in the process of updating an old app and am working on help screens.
I chose to display some useful How-tos through some html mainly for the ease of formatting the text (bullet points, colors, bold, underline etc...).
Since the app is a bit complex, The help screens are in a total of 3:
A main info webpage that links to 2 other detailed pages.

Tha app is localized in English (Base) and French.

Once the setup was complete, and with everything working fine, I went ahead and localized the base html files.

Now, they are neatly placed in the Base.lproj and fr.lproj files.

But when when I tap on a link to another page from the main WebView, nothing happens !

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Here are some bits of code I'm using:
In the .h file :

```
@interface howToViewController : UIViewController <WKUIDelegate>  
{  
    WKWebView *infoText;  
    NSString *uRLString;  
}  
@property (nonatomic, retain) WKWebView *infoText;
```

In the .m file: (had to programmatically create the WKWebView because of the known Xcode 9 bug when creating it through Storyboards)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  
{  
    [super viewDidLoad];  
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKWebView *aWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame  
                                         configuration:theConfiguration];  
aWebView.UIDelegate = self;  
self.infoText = aWebView;  

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"infoHTML" withExtension:@"html"];  
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];  
NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];  

[infoText loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseUrl];  

[self.view addSubview:infoText];  
}
```

In the html file, the links that no longer work once the files are localized:

```
<p>3/ More information is available for the respective tabs by pressing the following links :</p>  
    <ul><li><a href="pageOne.html">Limitations</a>  
    </li></ul>  
    <ul><li><a href="pageTwo.html">Fueling</a>  
    </li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working code from one of my apps. I'm using NSURLRequest and WKWebView's loadRequest instance method. I'm not sure what's going wrong with your use of loadHTMLString:baseURL: but I think it may have something to do with the value you're passing for the baseURL argument. Have you cleared the console, then single-stepped over that line of code to see if you're getting any message in the console?

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: pageString withExtension: @"html"]; 
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
[webView loadRequest: request];
```

Comment: Thank you for this response CodeWriter23. Tried it but no joy : loading of page 1 or 2 is still erratic...

Had some luck with

href="Base.lproj/pageTwo.html">Fueling</a>
Or

href="fr.lproj/pageTwo.html">Fueling</a>
But still very inconsistent.

Ended up using buttons on top of view to load proper html directly...

Comment: Looking back to your original technique, have you tried setting the baseURL to be the localized bundle folder?

Comment: Yes, I have, inspired by these two other threads :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001671/localizing-html-files-in-xcode and,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448995/html-file-localization
But, again ran into inconsistent behavior...
To be safe, I took another approach: Top Tool Bar with 3 buttons: MAIN PAGE1 PAGE2 that each link to an action:

Comment: `- (IBAction)mainButtonPushed:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *urlToLoad = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"html"];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlToLoad encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
    [self.infoText loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseUrl];
    
    self.mainBarButton.tintColor = [UIColor kSelectedTint];
    self.page1BarButton.tintColor = [UIColor kUnselectedTint];
    self.page2BarButton.tintColor = [UIColor kUnselectedTint];
}
`

Comment: Very new to this... I guess I should post new code in an **Answer** rather than in a **Comment**...

Comment: If the buttons at the top work for you, that's cool. Those kind of things gnaw away at my subconscious until I figure it out, and if that's the case for you, my suggestion follows...

Here's what I would do in your situation. Go back to the code pre-localization that worked. In the simulator, use NSLog to output the NSURL path used for baseURL to the console. Explore the file system at that location. Then go to the new version and do the same thing. Something is different...so what is it that is different?